# How to perform a query to compare a table against itself based on a timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table products that contains a snapshot of an entire product line at a current timestamp.

So each day the entire product table is saved in this same table, with the timestamp.

```
product_id  price  inventory_count snapshot
1           22     23              20160915
1           22     20              20160916
```

I want to query this table, and list all products where the inventory_count changed.

How can I do this?

I'm not sure how I can inner join the table on itself using the snapshot somehow to differentiate them.

Comment: What range of time do you want to cover?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just want to compare 2 periods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a self join:

```
select p.*, p2.inventory_count
from products p join
     products p2
     on p.product_id = p2.product_id and
        p.timestamp = 20160915 and
        p2.timestamp = 20160916
where p.inventory_count <> p2.inventory_count;
```

This only lists products in both snapshots.  You may want to find missing products as well.  If so, use `full join`:

```
select p.*, p2.inventory_count
from products p full join
     products p2
     on p.product_id = p2.product_id and
        p.timestamp = 20160915 and
        p2.timestamp = 20160916
where p.inventory_count <> p2.inventory_count or
      p.product_id is null or p2.product_id is null;
```